# Google sees links that are not encoded

Tags: google, wordpress, links

I'm working on an already existing project from a new client, so I am not very aware of the websites history. Also I barely ever touch SEO topics so I do lack knowlegde in this area.
There are couple different language versions on the website. The main domain is something like this:

```
www.example.com
```

And the other versions are:

```
www.example.eu/en
www.example.eu/es
www.example.eu/fr
```

etc. I will refer to those as "correct links" in the post.

The main difference is the `eu` instead of `com`

Now, on top of the website is menu where I can change the language and the links are the way I listed them above aka they are correct, and thats the way they should be visible.

- When I hover with my mouse over them I can see the correct links
- When I inspect the code with chrome dev tools I see the correct links

But

- when I scan the website with tools like screaming frog or xenu
- when I right click on the website and browse the websites source code

What I see is something like this `www.example.com/fr` etc.
I assume they might have been urls of older version of the website, as they are redirected to the correct urls in htaccess file. However I would like the google to see the correct links instead of those. Also, when I type `site:www.example.com/fr` and see the copy in the google, I can see that the google robots have recently visited the website and I think it should not be indexed since it's redirected right?

One more thing, I don't know if this might have any impact on the case but there is installed WP plugin called `WPGlobus` which seems to be used to manage different language versions of the website.

So my question is, is there something obvious I'm missing here, or maybe is there something I could do about it to make the google index correct links and not see the old ones?

Comment: Can you confirm the links you have moused over, that are correct, are the ones Xenu is finding? Or could it be that there are other old links on the site - such as links within Posts and Pages, in the content itself - that are pointing to the old URLs? It would be wise to search through the theme, plugins, and database for any reference to the old URLs and update them wherever they are found.